# RStudio does not display any output in console after entering code

Tags: r

The problem is that when I run the code, there's no return in the console; I mean it does run the code, but does not return any output.

For example, if I write

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
v
```

I would expect in return

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

But it's not working.

I have version RStudio Version 0.98.1079 and R Version 3.1.1

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a code block or or a quote left open? Are you typing commands at a proper `>` prompt or is there a `+` prompt? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Also try typing: `sink()`

Comment: I reinsatlled RStudio this morning and has been working, but now is not working again, I do see that I have a + prompt i  the Rstudio console. Could It be the reason? I do not know how does it happen.

Comment: I have the same problem sometimes.  When I print an object it doesn't work. When I print it again it works. It's an R bug. Maybe related with some package. I'm using data.table.

Answer (score 93):

Possibility 1 (until the + sign was mentioned): I was wondering if you had been doing a tutorial where they were demonstrating the `sink` function and you hadn't gotten to the point where it was reversed.

```
> sink('out.txt')  # diverts all output to a disk file
> v <- c(1,2)
> v       # output went to file
> sink()  # sets the output back to the console
> v
[1] 1 2
```

Another way would be to call `closeAllConnections`:

```
> sink('out.txt')
> v
> v
> closeAllConnections()
> v
[1] 1 2
```

Possibility 2: To address the lack of response with a "+" showing at the Rstudio console ... that is a sign that the R parser "thinks" the entered text has not completed a full R command. It may indicate that you haven't typed a closing bracket or parenthesis. If typing one or two of those is unsuccessful and you keep getting mor `+`'s then you may be successful with typing the `[esc]`-key. If it is showing up immediately after a restart then you should check your code for correctness and make sure that the `.Rdata` file is deleted from your working directory. If you don't know what that means then you may need to search for the methods appropriate to your operating system. You could also have an error in the code of one of your `.rprofile` files.

In any case these two possibilities have nothing to do with Rstudio per se and everything to to with the typical behavior of an R console session in pretty much any IDE.

Possibility unique to Rstudio:
Rstudio has weird focus-oriented design .... obviously my opinion based on other IDE experiences. If your focus is not on the console or an edit panel and was somewhere other than the Console, perhaps on the History panel, you will not see any response in the console panel. It seems to me that the default focus should be on the Console, but at startup, one needs to click on the "active" line of the console. And it you manage to swipe up as you right click you will accidentally "inspect an element" which completely covers up the Console panel.

Comment: thank you, I have not tried these options yet, since this morning I reinstalled RStudio and worked all morning, but know it failed again, I do not know if it has something to do with the + prompt in the RStudio console.

Comment: I have been finding that the sink() does not always send the output back to the console.  The closeAllConnections() seems to have solved that.  Thanks.

Comment: insidious - eg, if your script throws an error before it reaches `closeAllConnections`. Remember to call it again before turning sink off to debug

Comment: This was killing me. Hitting [esc] key in Console solved it. I had the + sign  at each line instead of a command caret (>).

Comment: I also had the same issue of + coming in the console with codes instead of executing the codes. Tried `sink()`, `closeAllConnections`, `Esc` and started a new R session didn't change anything. Finally, I debugged my code and removed an unnecessary `if(condition){}` condition, and it worked.

Answer (score 17):

Do the lines still start with a "+"? It is also possible you forgot to close the brackets of a function. Try "}".

Comment: it's not a good answer. For such things - it's better to use **comments**. Read here how to write a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Perhaps hitting ‘escape’.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and none of the tips mentioned here were working.

`Session > Restart R` did the trick for me, possibly suggesting that I had a similar problem as andrewH but was not patient enough to wait for R to behave again.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very old question, but I just had the same problem with a different cause, so I thought I would describe it here case it should be useful to someone else. I was getting the regular command prompt, with nothing more, no matter what I typed at the command line. I tried multiple returns, escape, sink, traceback, closeAllConnections (which did give me a response, "error: unexpected `)` in `()`, but then went back to the command prompt and ignored a second traceback).

Anyway after half an hour or so of pulling my hair out, up pops "View(Mid2)". Mid2 is a tibble with 8.5 million observations of 88 numeric variables. I must have tapped it in the environment pane accidentally. I suppose it just took that long for the viewer to render it. I assume that all the other things I did hit at once, because RStudio crashed immediately thereafter.

The interesting thing about this particular version of the problem is what didn't happen. The red stop sign in the upper right of the console window, that lights when R is busy, didn't light. That is unfortunate -- but understandable, if the RStudio viewer is a different process. But also, when my computer is working hard on a really big computation or IO task, the fan usually starts, but it didn't. Don't know why. . I took its absence, incorrectly, to mean no such computation was underway.

Comment: Would the esc-key interrupt?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found is `closeAllConnections` and/or `sink` which almost always work

But as a stop gap measure, `View()`'ing always works. It's sort of a pain but whatever you wanted to print out, surround by `View` and you can see it

Comment: I was having this issue when I use `browser` inside the server function of a shiny app and I couldn't see any of the outputs for the expressions I entered. Running `closeAllConnections` solved it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using R Studio Cloud, refresh or re-opening won't work.
Only clue from the above posts or answers is your console will always start with '+'
In my case I tried all possibilities of closing braces.
And ")" worked for me when I typed that into the console and press enter.

sink() function did nothing in R Studio Cloud

Answer (score 0):

A simple mistake might have also caused this problem:
A rather lengthy command left abandoned in the console is blocking the appearance of the result line.

Thus, the console only shows that line, but the result from any code run from the source, will not appear.

To solve this, just switch to the console, remove any remaining command and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing something like that explained here as an unresponsive console to the R-Code running was just devastating for me when I experienced it. But luckly although I tried every trick explained in this page, it did not work for me. At last I clicked on the "To console" option available just below the Environment, History, Connections, Tutorial Tab on the R Studio. It solved the puzzle for me just now.

Comment: Rstudio has weird focus-oriented design .... obviously my opinion based on other IDE experiences.  Sounds like your focus was somewhere other than the Console, perhaps on the History panel or an editing panel. It seems to me that the default focus should be on the Console, but at startup, one needs to click on the "active" line of the console. And it you manage to swipe up as you right click you will accidentally "inspect an element" which completely covers up the Console panel.

Answer (score -2):

If the lines in console are starting with "+".
Save your work and close the 'RStudio' or other tool which you are using and Start it again, it worked for me.

Comment: Bad advice. Instead, one should hit the `escape key` in the situation you mention. It's also a bad idea to save sessions, because it introduces a state where packages get loaded without you realizing it and you have variables being define that you forget. Incomprehensible error message then start appearing. Instead you should compose your sessions in the editor and submit to the console. Save your code from the editor so you can save teh text and the data objects separately.