# Console shows no ouput rstudio

Tags: r, console, rstudio

```
library(readxl)
library(writexl)
library(plyr)   
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
```

I have the following packages loaded within my code and code after. But at some point the console stops reacting to how it normally should. For example when the console is working properly:

```
'> 1
[1] 1
> 1
[1] 1
```

But after awhile there is no response:

```
> 1
> 1+1
> 1+1
>
```

What is the problem? This is every time I use rstudio.

```
> 1
[1] 1
```

This is shown again once I ctrl+shift+F10 to restart the R session. But runs into a dormant state in the console again when I compile the code. Does this mean something in the code is causing the console to not respond? Please help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RStudio does not display any output in console after entering code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495498/rstudio-does-not-display-any-output-in-console-after-entering-code)

Comment: I think it's safe to assume the libraries you loaded are irrelevant. Exactly what kind of R session is it? In any event, it's most likely one of the options listed in the thread Marius linked.

Comment: `> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Korean_Korea.949  LC_CTYPE=Korean_Korea.949    LC_MONETARY=Korean_Korea.949 LC_NUMERIC=C                
[5] LC_TIME=Korean_Korea.949    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1    yaml_2.1.19   
>`

Comment: The sink() or closeAllConnections() functions do not work for me. It's frustrating when this happens every time I'm compiling. Another hypothesis is that I'm compiling a large amount of code at a time and when there is an error within the code it progresses to resulting in what I have explained above.