# Stuck in infinite loop, where is the problem I am seeing?

Tags: r, function, infinite-loop

My code is stuck in an infinite loop, with the stop sign occurring. I have read through it multiple times, can anyone help?

I am trying to run trials using samples of possession probabilities and the subsequent make probabilities for a basketball team. I am following along with a video and made sure each step was completed properly.

How can I tell where I am stuck in an infinite loop and how do I fix it?

```
mc_hoops_ex <- function(trials) {
  
  prob_pos <- c(0.148, 0.544, 0.308, 0.256)
  prob_2pm <- 0.524
  prob_3pm <- 0.378
  prob_ftm <- 0.761
  prob_orb <- 0.319
  
  a <- 1
  pts_ct <- 0
  
  while (a <= trials) {
    
    pos_outcome <- sample(c(1:4), 1, prob = prob_pos)
    
    if(pos_outcome == 2) {
      
      pos_end <- 0
      
      while (pos_end < 1) {
        
        shot_prob <- runif(1)
        
        if(shot_prob <= prob_2pm) {
          
          pts_ct <- pts_ct + 2
          pos_end <- 1
        }
        
        else {
          
          orb_prob <- runif(1)
          if(orb_prob >= prob_orb)
            
            pos_end <- 1
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(pos_outcome == 3) {
    
    pos_end <- 0
    
    while (pos_end < 1) {
      shot_prob <- runif(1)
      
      if(shot_prob <= prob_3pm) {
        
        pts_ct <- pts_ct + 3
        pos_end <- 1
        
      }
      
      else {
        
        orb_prob <- runif(1)
        if(orb_prob >= prob_orb)
          
          pos_end <- 1
        
      }
    }
  }
  if(pos_outcome == 4) {
    
    pos_end <- 0
    
    while (pos_end < 1) {
      
      shot_prob <- runif(1)
      
      if(shot_prob <= prob_ftm) {
        
        pts_ct <- pts_ct + 1
        pos_end <- 1
      }
      
      else {
        
        orb_prob <- runif(1)
        if(orb_prob >= prob_orb)
          
          pos_end <- 1
        
      }
    }
  }
  
  a <- a + 1
  
  print(pts_ct / trials)
  print((pts_ct / trials) * 66.3)
}
```

Comment: @AlonEitan, how can I tell. I am using the default settings

Comment: @HolyBlackCat apologies, I didnt know the language so I included all of them to make sure I could reach someone to help

Answer (score 0):

This looks like R code, based on the syntax, `<-` assignment, and functions like `c()` and `runif()`.

You have the following loop: `while (a <= trials)`. This loop will continue running until the condition no longer holds. Since you initialize `a <- 1`, this loop will not stop unless (1) `trials < 1`, in which case the loop will not run a single time, or (2) `a` is incremented until `a > trials`.

We can see that the only time `a` is changed is near the bottom of the function: `a <- a + 1`. However, look closely at the braces. This increment is *outside* the while-loop, so it never occurs and the loop runs forever.

I'm not sure if this will produce the expected results, but a corrected version that does not have an infinite loop is given below.

```
mc_hoops_ex <- function(trials) {
  
  prob_pos <- c(0.148, 0.544, 0.308, 0.256)
  prob_2pm <- 0.524
  prob_3pm <- 0.378
  prob_ftm <- 0.761
  prob_orb <- 0.319
  
  a <- 1
  pts_ct <- 0
  
  while (a <= trials) {
    
    pos_outcome <- sample(c(1:4), 1, prob = prob_pos)
    
    if(pos_outcome == 2) {
      
      pos_end <- 0
      
      while (pos_end < 1) {
        
        shot_prob <- runif(1)
        
        if(shot_prob <= prob_2pm) {
          
          pts_ct <- pts_ct + 2
          pos_end <- 1
        }
        
        else {
          
          orb_prob <- runif(1)
          if(orb_prob >= prob_orb)
            
            pos_end <- 1
          
        }
      }
    }
# Removed the closing brace here
    if(pos_outcome == 3) {
      
      pos_end <- 0
      
      while (pos_end < 1) {
        shot_prob <- runif(1)
        
        if(shot_prob <= prob_3pm) {
          
          pts_ct <- pts_ct + 3
          pos_end <- 1
          
        }
        
        else {
          
          orb_prob <- runif(1)
          if(orb_prob >= prob_orb)
            
            pos_end <- 1
          
        }
      }
    }
    if(pos_outcome == 4) {
      
      pos_end <- 0
      
      while (pos_end < 1) {
        
        shot_prob <- runif(1)
        
        if(shot_prob <= prob_ftm) {
          
          pts_ct <- pts_ct + 1
          pos_end <- 1
        }
        
        else {
          
          orb_prob <- runif(1)
          if(orb_prob >= prob_orb)
            
            pos_end <- 1
          
        }
      }
    }
    
    a <- a + 1
  }  # Added a closing brace here instead
  
  print(pts_ct / trials)
  print((pts_ct / trials) * 66.3)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My only problem now is that its not printing the number I want, rather it is just copying the complete function when I run it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You can run the function with ```mc_hoops_ex(trials)``` where ```trials``` is set to whatever number you want. For example, ```mc_hoops_ex(2)``` will run the function with ```trials``` set to 2.

Comment: I run it in the console but nothing results i type `mc_hoops_ex(1)` and nothing happens or shows up

Comment: Hmm...that is strange. I would expect an error to show up at least if something was wrong. Maybe ```print()``` doesn't work for you? What if you try removing the last two lines of the function (the two lines with ```print()```), and instead add the line ```return(c(pts_ct / trials, (pts_ct / trials) * 66.3))```? Try that and see if two numbers show up for you.

Comment: Still nothing, nothing shows up in console. Should I restart RStudio?

Comment: Here are some ideas to track down the problem. (1) Look in the global environment window. Do you see ```mc_hoops_ex``` there? Click on it to bring up its definition, and look through that definition. Does it have the changes you made? If not, you might need to rerun the code that defines the function. (2) Based on a quick Google search I did, maybe console output is being redirected somewhere. Try running ```sink()``` or ```closeAllConnections()``` and then rerun the code. Does it output to the console now?

Comment: FYI: that Google search brought me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26496781/15255215) StackOverflow answer.