# Variables Not Being Defined in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Very new to R, no clue what's going wrong. I'm trying to build a linear regression model following an example from my stats class. This is my current code

```
players <- c(6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10)
time <- c(353, 312, 315, 420, 464, 404, 423, 482, 495)
amogus <- data.frame(players, time)

ggplot(amogus, aes(x = players, y = time)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE) +
  labs(title = "Among Us Data",
       subtitle = "scatterplot", 
       caption = "Math 032") +
  theme_minimal()
```

I had issues with defining variables and the data frame, but it finally looks like I got it working. I checked if every variable existed, which they did, however the `players` variable wasn't correct. When I go input `print(players)` I receive the output

```
 > print(players)
[1] 1 2 3
```

I've tried rewriting the code in a new file and I still have the same issue.

UPDATE

After some help, I was able to get my variables correctly defined. When I tried running the code for the graph, I was met with an error saying the function `ggplot` could not be found. I saw that I had to install/load `ggplot2`, which I did. I'm no longer receiving an error, but now the console is just outputting a blank line every time I run the code.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495498/rstudio-does-not-display-any-output-in-console-after-entering-code

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<-` instead of `->` for your `players` vector. When printing `players`:

```
> print(players)
[1]  6  6  7  8  8  8  8  9 10
```

You can use the following code:

```
players <- c(6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10)
time <- c(353, 312, 315, 420, 464, 404, 423, 482, 495)
amogus <- data.frame(players, time)

library(tidyverse)
ggplot(amogus, aes(x = players, y = time)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = TRUE) +
  labs(title = "Among Us Data",
       subtitle = "scatterplot", 
       caption = "Math 032") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Ahh crap, I noticed that issue and then changed in R, but not in this posts. `players` is still being defined as what was stated in the posts. My apologies. Edit: I even copy/pasted the code you provided, and the scatterplot was the same as it was. I printed again the variable and nothing changed.

Comment: @brandon_ducks, maybe try rerunning your variables? Check if it works using my code above.

Comment: I deleted the old file and ran a new one. The variable is now defined, they each exist and are printing as they should. The rest of the code for the plot, however, is just returning the old, incorrect one. It looks like it's still reading `players` as its old definition.

Comment: @brandon_ducks, you should clean your environment. When using a new file, the variables won't disappear. You should clean your environment by using `rm(list=ls())` in your console for example.

Comment: I cleared the environment and restarted RStudio. I ran the code again, first checking that everything was still defined correctly (it was), but I didn't get any output in the console, nor a plot. I feel like I'm making a dumb mistake somewhere.

Comment: @brandon_ducks, did you load all the necessary packages like `library(tidyverse)`?

Comment: Yes. I loaded tidyverse, then got an error saying the ggplot function could not be found, so I then loaded "ggplot2" and this is where the issue began.

Comment: @brandon_ducks, Maybe you can share your errors in your question above?

Comment: I have added an update.